# To display the field values submitted with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Here is the code:I want to post the field values entered in this code to the page ajaxpost.php using Ajax and then do some operations there. What would be code required to be written in ajaxpost.php

```
             <html>
             <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
          function loadXMLDoc()
        {
           var xmlhttp;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                 }
         else
           {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
                }
                 var zz=document.f1.dd.value;   //alert(zz);
                var qq= document.f1.cc.value;
             xmlhttp.open("POST","ajaxpost.php",true);
               xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               xmlhttp.send("dd=zz&cc=qq");
         }
              </script>
            </head>
           <body>

         <h2>AJAX</h2>
      <form name="f1">
             <input type="text" name="dd">
            <input type="text" name="cc">
             <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
             <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </form>
            </body>
               </html>
```

Comment: "Some operations".....?  How can we possibly tell you what code to write for this?

Comment: NO I WANT THE POSTED FIELD VALUES (I HAD USED 2 INPUT FIELDS ,I NEED TO GET THAT POSTED VALUE, if i get it i can do the operations. I WANT TO KNOW HOW CAN WE GET THE POSTED VALUES IN ajaxpost.php

Comment: when i try with $_POST[fname]; in ajaxpost.php, i am not getting the 1st input field value, instead getting only value as zz ,But i had used in code var zz=document.f1.dd.value;

Comment: Did your caps lock get stuck? Why are you yelling at AJ?

Comment: No I did not mean anything bad with using CapsLOck, Just used it not for meaning anything bad,

Comment: and also sorry if turning capslock had made a bad feeling for others. I did'nt mean to hurt anyone

Comment: Has the discussion stopped, I did not even think like what jen had pointed out

Answer (score 0):

concat the vlue with url, like below code.,

include the jquery js and reffer below code.

```
 $.ajax({       
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxpost.php?dd=zz&cc=qq,
    success: function(msg){ 
        //bind result to HTML element
    }
});
```

Comment: use jquery to call ajax it's very simple.

Comment: is it that difficult to post the value on ajxpost.php using ajax alone

Answer (score 0):

For playing with AJAX, I recommend using jQuery as it makes it much easier to use.
Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info.

All that you need to do is:

```
$.ajax({
//GET or Post
    type: 'POST',
//Page you want to use to do stuff with
    url: 'ajaxpost.php',
//The data that you are going to send.
    data: {dd:$('#dd').val(), cc:$('#cc').val()},
//What sort of data to expect back (can be JSON, HTML, XML, etc)
    dataType: 'html',
//function that will deal with the data that you get back
    success: function(data){ /* do stuff */
});
```

The php file ajaxpost.php just needs to read the $_POST and then 'do stuff'.  Echo the results of the what ever you want to the page and that will be used by the success function.  Just make sure that the data is returned in the right type for what the script expects.